# PHP code for generating a simple coupon code

Tags: php, coupon

I need some help automatically generating 250 coupon codes when i run the program.

It must:

- create 250 coupon codes
- the coupon codes must be 10 characters long
- the coupon codes must begin with "IA"

This is my code:

```
function generateCouponCode($length = 10) {
    $chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $ret = '';
    for($i = 0; $i < $length; ++$i) {
        'prefix'=>'IA',
        $random = str_shuffle($chars);
        $ret .= $random[250];
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you already have code to do this. If it doesn't work, you need to explain *how* it doesn't work.

Comment: And next time please spend a bit more time getting your code showing properly...

Answer (score 0):

This might work.

```
function coupon($l){

  $coupons = array();

  for($i = 0;$i < 250;$i++){
      $r=  "IA".substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat('0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',$l-2)),0,$l-2);
  array_push($coupons,$r);
  }

   //returns 250 coupons as an array
   return $coupons;

}

coupon(10);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question but the code you provided doesnt seem to be working. When i run the code nothing happens. Whereas in my code when i run the program the result is something like this: IAS3DJ6BW IA3JS1HSK

Answer (score 0):

```
function coupon($l){

  $coupons = array();

  for($i = 0;$i < 250;$i++){
      $r=  "IA".substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat('0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',$l-2)),0,$l-2);
  array_push($coupons,$r);
  }

   //returns 250 coupons as an array
   return $coupons;

}

coupon(10);
```

This returns an array.

Try `print_r(coupon(10));` instead of `coupon(10);`